# Radio buttons Knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have 2 values that I get from server A and B. I can only have one true at a time.

Again what I need is one of the radios to be checked at a time so one true value only.

```js
var viewModel = {
    radioSelectedOptionValue: ko.observable("false"),
    A: ko.observable("false"),
    B: ko.observable("false") 
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class='liveExample'>    
        <h3>Radio View model</h3>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Radio buttons:</td>
            <td>
                <label><input name="Test" type="radio" value="True" data-bind="checked: A" />Alpha</label>
                <label><input name="Test" type="radio" value="True" data-bind="checked: B" />Beta</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>  
    A-<span data-bind="text: A"></span>
    B-<span data-bind="text: B"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/hamsaya/cyBQH/2/

Comment: This is another wonderful answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20080917/683157

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The `checked` binding works differently for radio buttons and checkboxes:

From the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html):

> For radio buttons, KO will set the element to be checked  **if and only
>   if** the parameter value equals the radio button node’s `value` attribute.
>   So, your parameter value should be a **string**.

So you need to set the `value` attribute of your inputs to "A" and "B" and then bind to the `radioSelectedOptionValue` which will contain "A" or "B" depending on which options is selected:

```
<label>
    <input name="Test" type="radio" value="A" 
             data-bind="checked: radioSelectedOptionValue" />
    Alpha
</label>
<label>
    <input name="Test" type="radio" value="B" 
             data-bind="checked: radioSelectedOptionValue" />
    Beta
</label>
```

If you want to keep your boolean properties: `A` and `B`, you need to make them `ko.computed` (read-only, writable) which will use/convert the value of the `radioSelectedOptionValue`:

```
this.radioSelectedOptionValue = ko.observable();
this.A = ko.computed( {
        read: function() {
            return this.radioSelectedOptionValue() == "A";
        },
        write: function(value) {
            if (value)
                this.radioSelectedOptionValue("A");
        }
    }, this);
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/p8nSe/)

Comment: This is great but when i get my value from server it is already false or true I want the users radio button to be selected. I don't think this will check that.

Comment: Because in my sample A and B are writable computeds you can assign true or false to them. I've added a sample `loadDataFromServer` method in  http://jsfiddle.net/p8nSe/1/ to demo it.

Answer (score 32):

Knockout 3.x added the checkedValue binding option.  This allows you to specify values other than strings.

```
    <input name="Test" type="radio" data-bind="checked: radioSelectedOptionValue, checkedValue: true" />
    <input name="Test" type="radio" data-bind="checked: radioSelectedOptionValue, checkedValue: false" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t73d435v/

Comment: Tim, perhaps we could meet to discuss this further?  I am struggling with this on the new Hedges tab.

Comment: This is REALLY nice for when you are using a radio button as a switch.  Perfect.