# Binding checked for radio input using knockout mapping library

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Very simple `data-bind="checked: someBool"` that isn't checking my radio input.

`<input type="radio" data-bind="checked: someBool" />radio`

The ko code...

```
var data = { someBool: true };
var vm = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

The radio is un-checked. Am I missing something?

Live: http://jsbin.com/exokav/4/edit

Comment: possible duplicate of [Radio buttons Knockoutjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259537/radio-buttons-knockoutjs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a value attribute for the radio-button to map to. Also the value won't be a boolean, but a string after this. I use the following extension to use boolean values for radio buttons. (live: [http://jsbin.com/exokav/8](http://jsbin.com/exokav/8/edit)):

```
ko.bindingHandlers.checkedAsBool = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var observable = valueAccessor(),
            interceptor = ko.computed({
                read: function () {
                    var val = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(observable);
                    return ((val !== null) && (typeof val !== "undefined") ? val.toString() : val);
                },
                write: function (newValue) {
                    observable(newValue === "true");
                },
                owner: this
            });
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { checked: interceptor });
    }
};
```

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10127300/932282) answer by RP Niemeyer.

Comment: Off topic: ;-) If you like this answer, maybe you can also mark a correct answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9475893/932282

Comment: lol you're right @mhu. done and done. back to this post, I'll mark this answer as the right one, altho it's bummer because knockout's website makes it look so easy :/ http://i.imgur.com/U0qah8P.png screenshot, link to full article here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html

Comment: Thanks, now I'm a guru ;-). Yes, but that sample also uses checkboxes for boolean values.