# knockout data-bind for radio button

Tags: knockout.js, data-binding

I need to data bind the radio button to the value that comes from the database

html

```
 <input type="radio" name="dateRange" value="selectByDays" data-bind="checked: daysSelected">
```

I checked using the `pre data-bind` tag to see whether `daysSelected` is passed properly and it is. But the radiobox is still not being selected when daysSelected = true

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `checked` binding, when used with radio buttons, is designed to hold the value of the radio button selected - they would usually be in a group of radio buttons with different values all bound to the same observable.  Since your radio button has a value of `"selectByDays"`, that's what you need to set the value of the `daysSelected` observable to, rather than setting it to `true`.

Comment: yes, found that! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259537/radio-buttons-knockoutjs